# jquery deferred object callback not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have the following code

```
function get_hash(){
    id = $('#file_id').val()
    deferred =  $.ajax({ url: "/rest/hash_upload/", type: "GET", data: {file_id: id} })
    $.when(deferred).then(function(data){
        alert('executing')
        $('#input_md5_checksum').val(data)
    })
}
```

The ajax gets called and my backend returns the hash as expected. However, the deferred callback method does not fire. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably, because the `$.ajax()` request is failing in some manner. Either the response isn't `200 OK` or jQuery is attempting to parse the response and is unable to. Add a [`failFilter`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/#deferred-then-doneFilter-failFilter-progressFilter) or [`.fail()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) to see if an error is being reported. (Side note: `$.when()` isn't really necessary for a single `deferred`, which will have its own `.then()` you can use.)

Comment: Thanks. It was because I didn't have a dataType: text attribute, so it was presumably trying to parse json.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the `$.when()` here is redundant. You can just use `deferred.then(...)` or call `.then()` directly on the result of `$.ajax()` without first storing it in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why set your query as a variable and and then use `when()`, why not just use a regular ajax call?

```
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "/rest/hash_upload/", 
            type: "GET", 
            data: {file_id: id} 
        }).done(function(data){
            alert('executing');
            $('#input_md5_checksum').val(data);
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
            return ("Ajax failed: " + xhr.responseText);
        });
```

Comment: Be sure to explain what the OP did wrong and what you did differently. It's not much of an answer without explanation.

Comment: @TomKriek I posted that by accident, it was just his code reposted, and was in the middle of editing my answer.

Comment: There is no reason to use $.when or .then in this case, but, this probably could have been presented as a comment.

Comment: As I understand it, deferred is now the preferred way instead of using success.

Comment: @shaw2thefloor that is correct, but, that doesn't mean you have to use .then and .when in order to use the deferred. `.done` is a method on any promise(deferred) object too.

Comment: No but I was asked "why not just use a regular ajax call?", I presume meaning, why use deferred objects at all.

Comment: @shaw2thefloor The text in the answer here is a bit missleading, since using .done is still using what you are referring to as a deferred object (it's actually a promise)

Comment: @shaw2thefloor `.done` is preferred to `success` but I dont think `.when` and `.then` are preferred to regular ajax calls.

Comment: @shaw2thefloor Using deferred methods is possibly more common, but the `success:` option for `jQuery.ajax()` is still valid to use. There was, however, a short-lived `.success()` method that could have been used in place of [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) that has been deprecated.

Comment: @Craicerjack Then all is well :)